# POST request to API on Heroku working on Postman but not on React Heroku app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, axios, cloudflare

I have an API on Heroku hosted at `https://api.MYCUSTOMDOMAIN.ca` that I tried sending an axios POST request to through `https://www.MYCUSTOMDOMAIN.ca` which turns into a GET request and is logged in Heroku as a OPTIONS request, but the same POST request made through Postman to the API works as expected.

I've played around with CORS, thinking it might have something to do with preflights, however that doesn't seem to have done anything.

I've also seen comments on other articles about POST requests changing to GET request because of HTTP to HTTPS redirects. If this a possible cause, how would I prevent the lost data and the changed POST from happening?

Request Headers made through `https://www.MYCUSTOMDOMAIN.ca`

[image: Request headers made through www.MYCUSTOMDOMAIN.ca]

Response headers from https://api.MYCUSTOMDOMAIN.ca

[image: Response headers made through]

Heroku app log sample

[image: Heroku app logs]

EDIT: Upon request, here is my CORS setup in my app entrypoint.  `https://www.MYCUSTOMDOMAIN.ca` is one of the allowed origins specified in `corsWhitelist`.

```js
import express from "express";
import cors, { CorsOptions } from "cors";

const app = express();

const corsWhitelist: string[] = [ /* allowed origins */ ];

const corsOptions: CorsOptions = {
    origin: (origin: string | undefined, callback: Function) => {
        if(typeof(origin) === "string" && corsWhitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) callback(null, true);
        else callback(null, false);
    },
    credentials: true,
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTION"],
    optionsSuccessStatus: 204
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Comment: This is something with the CORS. Can you show your code how is your cors implemented. Also can you show the response header for the OPTIONS request.

Comment: @Panther please see the added code. And the OPTIONS log on Heroku was the only place I saw the OPTIONS, I didn't see a OPTIONS response in the Network tab of my Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to allow all and open it up completely.

```
// CORS //
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
```